# Part of my CSS stops working after I upload to Cpanel

Tags: html, css, cpanel

I recently bought a domain with my name and am making a "Resume Website" so to say, and have been slowly adding stuff to it. As the title says, while everything works fine when I view my Website locally, a part of the CSS just plain doesn't work after I upload it through cPanel. The stuff for my name works totally fine, but there's some introductory text at the bottom that should be white etc etc but isn't. You have to select it to see it since the background is black. 
URL: http://www.arberesati.com/

I haven't done much appart for looking at the code and it all looks fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Arber Esati</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:200,400|Montserrat:600|Open+Sans:300|Roboto:200|Text+Me+One%26effect=anaglyph"
            type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Cover page -->
        <div id="co">
            <div class="name">
                <h1 id="ae">Arber Esati</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="welcome">
            <h1 id="hi">Hi.</h1>
            <p id="intro">I'm a wannabe web designer, professionally tech-headed addicted to cars 17 year old.</p>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

```
/*
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Text Me One', sans-serif;*/

* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

#co {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.name {
     padding-top: 18%;
}

@keyframes btw {
    from {color: black;}
    to {color: white;}
}

#ae {
    text-shadow: 0 0 0;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 18%;
    font-size: 200px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    transition:text-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    padding: 0;
    animation: btw;
    animation-duration: 0.35s;
}

@keyframes wtb {
    from {color: white;}
    to {color: black;}
}

#ae.cool {
    animation: wtb;
    animation-duration: 0.35s;
    font-size: 200px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    -webkit-transition:text-shadow 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:text-shadow 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:text-shadow 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:text-shadow 0.35s ease-in-out;
    transition:text-shadow 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;        
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;      
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;     
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    text-shadow: -0.03em -0.03em red, 0.045em 0.045em cyan; 
    padding: 0;
}

#welcome {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 50px;
}

#hi {
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;   
}

#intro {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $(window).scroll($.debounce(250, true, function(e){
            $('#ae').toggleClass('cool');
        }));
    });
```

I hope someone has any idea what on earth could be going wrong.

Comment: In https://jsfiddle.net/xtop08bs/ everything works fine ( except the jquery part ) . Also, i visited your site and everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess it works now? Because for me the text is white. Tested in several browsers.

Comment: Lol I cleared cache and it works now... Note to self: always test in multiple browsers... thanks anyways :D

Comment: ALWAYS test in multiple browsers :P But I guess I shouldn't have answered... Did I get the downvote just because I haven't enough reputation to comment?

Comment: I tried to upvote you but because I'm new it doesn't show publically. No idea what that's about.

Comment: Accepting the answer saved it. Thanks :)